# How to activate jquery in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have just started on a Chrome extension and I need to use jQuery. I followed all the tutorials and Stackoverflow answers I could find, but it just isnt working.

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "some.site",
"description": "For adding assets to some.site.com",
"version": "1.0",

"permissions": [
"http://some.site.com",
"storage"
],
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://jquery.com/*"],
  "js": ["jquery-1.11.0.min.js"]
}
]
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">hello</div>
</body>

<script>

$('#test').html('booger');

</script>
</html>
```

Everything works fine when loaded directly in the browser, but when I click on the extension icon, it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried checking the JavaScript console for your popup page? I.e. open it, right-click and select "Inspect element". You might see a useful error message there. Also, are both `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` and `popup.html` in the same directory? (I guess they are since you said it works when loaded directly…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write inline scripts within Chrome Extension due to the Content Security Policy, so the following, inline code:

```
<script>

$('#test').html('booger');

</script>
```

won't even execute. You have to move it to the separate file.

More about that (and nice examples) at [Chrome Developer's Guide.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

The reason it works when loaded directly is because then - you simply treat the page as html document. The Chrome is not loading it as an extension and so, any restrictions are not applied.

Comment: That's another part of the story :)